# Show the data on tableview dynamically change according to user

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

If an user enetered in textfield,then a tableview will present and show the data according to user input, like if user insert A then all words starting from a show in tableview
for this i have show the tableview when user select textfield but i show all list of data like dropdown option , but client want to it will autocorrect

this is my code

```
 in textfielddidbeginediting:---

    if (textField ==_stateTextField)
{
    _stateView.hidden = NO;
    _cityView.hidden  = YES;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [_tableView reloadData];

}

 **in tableview method** 
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
    return [_stateListArray count];
  }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
StateListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (!cell)
{
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"StateListCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
cell.listLabel.text = [_stateListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
_stateName = [_stateListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
_stateTextField.text =_stateName;
_stateView.hidden = YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your function in shouldChangeCharactersInRange as this method calls every time you entered on text field:-

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range   replacementString:(NSString *)string {
     NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
     // Your function here
     return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range   replacementString:(NSString *)string {
//Your Code
[tableView reloadData];
  }
```

delegate method and then reload the table.

Hope will help you.